# correct use of resource-agent-allocation

Tags: anylogic

My problem is that I have three different types of "agents "that can be transported by three different "resources".

Now I am not sure how best to implement this in AnyLogic.

My first thought was to assign this rule in the Seize block at "Action". However, I did not get further with this approach.

[first option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Rap8.png)

My second thought was to make a case distinction using the Output block. Each path is for a specific resource.

[second option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZ5et.png)

[function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWAr5.png)

[Select Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSK9E.png)

However, I get an error message here: Error during model startup:

root.selectOutputOut:
Parameter selectOutputIn is not specified (null/empty).

This is probably the problem that I have not selected a specific agent. However, this is also not possible since I have three different agents coming in.

Another consideration is that after the agents are created, a separate list is generated for each resource with the tasks that can be executed and deleted from the local list after assignment. This seemed even more complicated and I have not found an approach to implement this.

Does anyone have a suggested solution as to how I best go about defining this rule?

As you can see I tried several ways to fix it but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Always read your error messages carefully. Your current problem is just that: you did not define the SelectOutPutIn block

[image: OPs screenshot but edited]

Most of the time there are multiple correct ways to approach a problem in AnyLogic. I think in your case using these SelectOutput blocks correctly could be one of them.